# How to make a function in alert button in iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I made an alert view with OK button in the didRecieveRemoteNotification method. The Ok button has a function when you click it, but the function that i call is in the same class. what if that function is in another class? how can i call that class when i click the OK button.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userPushInfo
    {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionary =[userPushInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryalert = [fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"alert"];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionarybody = [fetchedDictionaryalert objectForKey:@"body"];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryactivation = [fetchedDictionarybody objectForKey:@"activation_code"];

    if(fetchedDictionaryactivation != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryresult = [fetchedDictionaryactivation objectForKey:@"result"];
        for (NSDictionary *user in fetchedDictionaryresult)
        {
            responseActCode = [user objectForKey:@"activation_code"];
            responseParentID = [user objectForKey:@"parent_id"];
            NSLog(@"Item actcode: %@", responseActCode);
            NSLog(@"Item parentid: %@", responseParentID);
        }
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle:@"Activation Code"
                    message:(@"%@", responseActCode)
                    delegate:self
                    cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                    otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
        alertView.tag = 0;
        NSLog(@"dadadad %@", userPushInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionary =[userPushInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryalert = [fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"alert"];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionarybody = [fetchedDictionaryalert objectForKey:@"body"];
        NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryresult = [fetchedDictionarybody objectForKey:@"result"];
        NSString *beaconID;
        for (NSDictionary *user in fetchedDictionaryresult)
        {
            beaconID = [user objectForKey:@"beacon_id"];
            mess = [user objectForKey:@"message"];
            NSLog(@"Item actcode: %@", beaconID);
            NSLog(@"Item parentid: %@", mess);
        }

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@""
        message:(@"%@", mess)
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
        otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
        alertView.tag = 1;
        NSLog(@"dadadad %@", userPushInfo);

    }


}
```

Comment: Note: Be modern, use `UIAlertView` no more. Use `UIAlertController` instead. To solve your problem, use internal notifications.

Comment: Another words UIAlertView is deprecated since iOS 8. You should use `UIAlertController`. You may want to use it along with  `NSNotificationCenter`. Lookup in google for more details

Comment: In answer to your question, think about how you would  call a method in another class in general. Apply the same idea inside your alert view delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger functions on other class, you can use:

**in initiating view controller or app delegate**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_NAME" object:nil userInfo:@{@"custom_key": @"custom_value"}];
```

**in target class viewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(actionDetected:) name:@"CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_NAME" object:nil];
```

where `- (void)actionDetected:(NSNotification *)notif` is the function you want to trigger